# Share variables between steps in drone.io

Tags: continuous-integration, drone.io, shared-variable

It seems to me that drone.io does not share parameters across pipeline steps.
Is it possible to read the parameters for the plugins from a file, e.g. a directive 
like "from_file" similar to the already existing "from_secret"? This is how one could use it:

```
kind: pipeline
name: default

steps:
- name: get_repo_name
  image: alpine
  commands:
  - echo "hello" > .repo_name
- name: docker  
  image: plugins/docker
  settings:
    repo: 
      from_file: .repo_name
    username:
      from_secret: docker_username
    password:
      from_secret: docker_password
```

Answer (score 2):

Ability to read input from a file is more the choice of the plugin author, but creating plugins is a pretty simplistic thing as most of your variables just have to be called in as `PLUGIN_VARIABLE` and you can then offer such things.

- https://docs.drone.io/plugins/bash/

To show that some of the plugins do read from file, one such example is drone-github-comment:

```
steps:
- name: github-comment
  image: jmccann/drone-github-comment:1.2
  settings:
    message_file: file_name.txt
  when:
    status:
    - success
    - failure
```

FWIW, looking at your example though, it would seem you are looking to pass just the repo_name?  These variables are all present in a pipeline depending of course on the runner you are using, but for Docker you get all of these:

- https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/environment/reference/